# is there any way to give name object?

Tags: javascript

I have fetch API request like this

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/usersRecords')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>{
       console.log(data.usersRecords);
  });
```

When I do `console.log(data.usersRecords)`

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
 0: {"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill": 12 , "knock": 1}
 1:  {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 12 , "knock": 4}
 2:  {"id": 3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 8 , "knock": 4}
 length: 3
 __proto__: Array(0)
```

I have two URL needed to be fetch

```
 fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/usersRecords')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
           console.log(data.usersRecords);
      });
 fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/usersRecord1')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
           console.log(data.usersRecords1);
      });
```

I want to make an array like this from above fetch and use them to merge two API requests and sum their data of kill and knock only

```
var demo = {
     "key1": [{"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill": 12 , "knock": 1}, 
               {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 12 , "knock": 4},
               {"id": 3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 8 , "knock": 4}],

    "key2": [
             {"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill":12  , "knock": 4}, 
             {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 13 , "knock": 3},
             {"id":3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 5 , "knock": 1}]
 };
```

```
Further, I need to merge two URLs and sum their data kill and knock. So this is code to merge and sum their kill and knock.

    var res = demo.key1.map(function(item, idx) {
    return Object.keys(item).reduce(function(obj, key) {
        if (key == 'name') {
            obj[key] = item[key];
        } else {
            obj[key] = item[key] + demo.key2[idx][key];
        }

        return obj;
    }, {});
});
```

Comment: `console.log({key1: data.userRecords})`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks 
 can i ask one more question ?

Comment: You may ask as many questions as you like on stack overflow as long as they follow the guidelines set out

Comment: @JaromandaX
Suppose there is  var demo ={key1: data.userRecords};.Now I want use that demo outside the fetch. How can i ?

Comment: in a `.then` or by using async/await

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/usersRecords')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>{
       let myObject = {"key1" : data.usersRecords};
       console.log(myObject);
  });
```

Comment: How can i use now myObject variable outside the fetch ?

Comment: @BeginnerCoder - you can't - it's declared inside the last .then, and even if you made it a global, it would not be populated until that .then has run, and now we're into the realms of accessing asynchronous results outside of the asynchronous function which is a whole other minefield

Comment: @JaromandaX Then My Problem is to fetch two url and i want to make  one url key and and other key2.

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you look my question again please ?